# How to check the element type?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to determine if the selected element is a `input` type element.

```
var element = this.getElement();
console(element) => <input type='text' name='input' value ='test'> or something else
```

How do I check if selected element is input element.

I searched google and someone said it can be

`element.is('input')` but it gave me error saying `is` undefined.

Can anyone help me here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.is()` is part of jQuery.  Try `element.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input'`.

Comment: You can also use `toString()` method of the element: `console(element.toString())` --> `[object HTMLInputElement]` (if `element` was an `input` element).

Comment: duck duck goose: inp.name && inp.type && inp.value!=null; this lets you hit all form inputs, not just <input>. match type to hit specific types...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `element` is a DOM node, you could use it's `nodeName` property.

```
var input = document.createElement('input')
input.nodeName; //returns "INPUT"
```

So, in your example, you could check if it is an input using `element.nodeName === "INPUT"`

Alternatively, you could do that with jQuery using `$(element).is('input')` - although I wouldn't use jQuery for such mundane tasks :)